# What programming language to use for developing visual novel type game?

Tags: java, game-engine

I would like start to build my own framwork to make visual novel type games. I am fairly confident in using Java.
Please tell me if it is a good choice to use it to for that kinda development. I want to use fullHD images, hq animation to display and I'm not sure if java is a good choice or not, but in the other hand i would like my games to run on any platform.
If is not the good choice for my requierments please tell me what programming language should I use.

Thanks for taking your time to help sincerely and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you can do this with most 3rd generation languages. For this type of game you could do several things depending on how much control you want. If you want to render quads (2d planes with images on them) and texts, and be able to transform them and apply your own shader programs for visual effects take a look at slick utils and the light weight java game library (LWJGL), an openGL implementation.

just using java native code will limit you significantly, as well as just using native classes in other languages.

it not really the language you should search for but more the frameworks. I worked with LWJGL and it was quite hard to learn. but in my opinion easier to learn than serious frameworks within a language such as c or c++

Comment: Thanks LWJGL looks pretty awesome.

Comment: Search for "thinMatrix" on youtube, nice tutorials on subjects, very well explained. He also covers rendering 2-d images on screen. I think that is what you are looking for.